# how to submit a form using the modal preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The main logic for the form submission is to preview the form data in the bootstrap modal before the data is submitted. The modal is able to preview the form data as expected but unable to submit it into the database

controller class

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping("/bankdetails")
public class UserBankDetailsController {

```
private UserBankDetailsServiceImpl bankDetailsService;

public UserBankDetailsController(UserBankDetailsServiceImpl bankDetailsService) {
    this.bankDetailsService = bankDetailsService;
}


@GetMapping
public String listBankDetails(Model model) {
    List<UserBankDetails> listBankInfo = bankDetailsService.listUserBankDetails();
    model.addAttribute("listBankInfo", listBankInfo);
    return "bank_details/index";
}


@GetMapping("/new")
public String bankDetailsForm(Model model) {
    UserBankDetails bankInfo = new UserBankDetails();
    model.addAttribute("bankInfo", bankInfo);
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "User Bank Information Form");
    
    return "bank_details/user_bankdetails_form";
}

@PostMapping("/save")
public String addBankDetails(UserBankDetails userBankDetails, RedirectAttributes ra) {
    
    bankDetailsService.addUserBankDetails(userBankDetails);
    ra.addFlashAttribute("message", "User bank information saved succesfully");
    
    return "redirect:/bankdetails";
}
```

}

thymeleaf form

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="~{fragments :: page_head('User Form','none')}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="back-arrow-container">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
            <div ><a th:href="@{/bankdetails}" class="moving-circle"></a></div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="title">[[${pageTitle}]]</h2>
        <form id="bankInfoForm"  class="form-container" th:object="${bankInfo}">
            
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
            
            <div  class="form-row">
                <div class="form-column">
                    <label class="form-label">First Name</label> <input type="text"
                        class="form-input"  th:field="*{firstName}" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-column">
                    <label class="form-label">Last Name</label> <input type="text"
                        class="form-input" th:field="*{lastName}" required="required"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-column">
                    <label class="form-label">Account Number</label> <input type="text"
                        class="form-input"  th:field="*{accountNumber}"  required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-column">
                    <label class="form-label">Bank Name</label> <input type="text"
                        class="form-input"  th:field="*{bankName}" required="required"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-column">
                <label class="form-label">Bank Branch:</label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{branch}" class="form-input"
                       required="required"/>
                
            </div>
            
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="btn-block ">
                <div class="btn-block">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="previewFormData()">Preview</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </form>
    </div>
```

```
<!-- Preview Modal -->
<div th:replace="bank_details/preview :: preview_bank_info"></div>
 

<!-- java script code here
```

```js
<script>
function previewFormData() {
    var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
    var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
    var accountNumber = $('#accountNumber').val();
    var bankName = $('#bankName').val();
    var branch = $('#branch').val();

    // Populate modal fields
    $('#previewFirstName').text(firstName);
    $('#previewLastName').text(lastName);
    $('#previewAccountNumber').text(accountNumber);
    $('#previewBankName').text(bankName);
    $('#previewBranch').text(branch);

    // Show the modal
    $('#previewModal').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

preview modal

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<div th:fragment="preview_bank_info" class="modal fade" id="previewModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="previewModalLabel" >
<div class="modal-dialog" >
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" >Bank Information Preview</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form >
            <div class="bank_details">
                <p><strong>First Name:</strong></p>
                <p> <span id="previewFirstName"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Last Name:</strong> </p>
                <p><span id="previewLastName"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Account Number:</strong> </p>
                <p><span id="previewAccountNumber"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Bank Name:</strong></p>
                <p> <span id="previewBankName"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Bank Branch:</strong></p>
                <p> <span id="previewBranch"></span></p>
            </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="bankInfoForm">Save</button>
            </form>
            
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "unable to submit it into the database" -> Your question is too vague. Can you elaborate what exactly is the problem? What have you tried? What error messages do you get?